# UPDATE a Table when another has been modified

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, oledb

I have 2 tables in an Access Database. (SQL examples are fine).

The first table is a table called Reports.

The fields are :-

- ID
- ReportName
- ReportType

The second table is a Template, where a user will store a host of reports. The user modifies this template table each week. Below are the fields :-

- ID
- UserID
- ReportName
- ReportType
- ScheduledDate
- Completed
- AssignedBy

I have everything in my code working, but I overlooked something vital.

I need to reflect the changes a user may make to the Report Table, I.E, EDIT a reports name, into the Template Table, so that any instance of the edited report, now shows the new name.

I'm struggling to work out how I can do this?

Any help would be appreciated, it doesn't have to be exact code, more so the method.

Comment: You could have used triggers here if it were a sql db, probably you need to do in your code when Template table is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Only works for .adp project, you should be able to do this using a trigger.

something like

```
create <trigger_name>
ON Report
....
```